# Determining who owns a transferrable item in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a game where users can buy virtual items with virtual currency, and also give those items away to other users. We need to be able to track the history of the item (who bought it, who it was gifted to, etc) and the current owner. I'm struggling with some of the table design.

My thinking is to have this (with table design simplified slightly and constraints/keys/etc omitted for space):

```
TABLE order
id                 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
buyer_id           INT NOT NULL,
paid               INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
owned_item_id     INT NOT NULL,
------------------------------------------------------
TABLE owned_item
id                 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
store_product_id   INT NOT NULL,
owner_id           INT NOT NULL,
------------------------------------------------------
TABLE gift
id                 INT NOT NULL,
giver_id           INT NOT NULL,
receiver_id        INT NOT NULL,
owned_item_id      INT NOT NULL,
```

With the idea being that when an item is purchased, both an **`order`** and an **`owned_item`** are created for that item. If the item is gifted, then a new entry in the **`gift`** table is created and the `owner_id` field is updated.

This approach makes it very easy to determine who currently owns a given item. **However**, it has redundant data and leaves room for problems with data integrity. If the 'owner_id' field was set incorrectly, we might end up with records that an item that was purchased by A and gifted to B but is now inexplicably owned by C.

How should such a structure be normalized? I've considered eliminating the **`owned_item`** table:

```
TABLE order
id                 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
buyer_id           INT NOT NULL,
paid               INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
product_id         INT NOT NULL,
------------------------------------------------------
TABLE gift
id                 INT NOT NULL,
giver_id           INT NOT NULL,
receiver_id        INT NOT NULL,
order_id           INT NOT NULL,
```

I don't like this solution because finding all of the items that some person owns becomes a very complex operation (find every gift record X where the recipient is A and no later gift record exists for the same order, combined with find every order record Y where the buyer is A and no gift records exist for that order) but if that's the correct solution then I'll make do.

Comment: There are a million ways to go about this, but the first two that come to mind are these: 1) Create a table that tracks transactions. The structure could be some thing like: ItemId, CurrentOwnerId, Ordinal(this is the column that allows you to maintain an order of events), TransactionType.    The other idea that comes to mind is the concept of event sourcing. It may be a bit much to set up, but the audit potential is incredible

Comment: Can you merge the order and gift tables? That reduces some redundancy. An order is a transfer of an item from null to a user, and has a non-zero cost, whereas a gift is just a transfer, from a user to a user, with a zero cost.

Comment: If the transfer table would work, there is still some redundancy left, between the transfer table and the ownership table, but for the purposes of efficiency, I think that is acceptable. You'd have to put extra clauses on every query that simply needs to determine the current owner for an item, and that might get time-expensive.

Comment: FWIW I think the question is OK. We do get a lot of overly broad questions here, so a few edge cases do get caught up from time to time. I'll vote to reopen (we'll see what other community members think, I can't promise it will actually open).

Comment: @halfer : Thanks,that's an interesting solution, but it allows for invalid data if both giver and recipient are non-null and the cost is non-zero. Our system would only allow players to gift items, not sell them

Comment: You can make the recipient a non-nullable column, with a foreign key constraint, since an order and a gift both require this value.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't solve the invalid data problem. Or we can ignore the price if both giver and receiver are non-null, but then the price field is irrelevant, which still means the table isn't normalized

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would be a good 3nf schema for what you're looking to do.

Entities and transactions are kept generic in order to allow all entity / transaction relationships to be simplified.

```
-- An Entity is a person or business, as a party in a transaction
CREATE TABLE entity (
id                  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
entity_type         ENUM('store', 'person') NOT NULL
name                VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

-- Unique item types - items are each an instance of an item-type
-- e.g. the item "Steve's broom" may be an item of type "broom"
CREATE TABLE item_type (
id                  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name                VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

-- Non-unique item, instance of an item-type owned by an entity
CREATE TABLE item (
id                  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-- optionally include owner_id as a quick-reference to the current owner of the item
owner_id            INT NULL REFERENCES entity (id), 
-- FK to unique item types, e.g. "broom"
item_type_id        INT NOT NULL REFERENCES item_type (id), 
-- possible description, e.g. "Steve's broom"
description         VARCHAR NOT NULL 
);

-- A transaction is a sale, gift, or other method of transferrence
-- of an item between entities.  Transaction is a bad name, because
-- it's a reserved word.  That's why it's encased in ticks.
-- You'd probably be better off choosing a different generic name
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
id
-- transaction_type can be NULL in cases of origination with entity
transaction_type    ENUM('sale', 'gift') NULL,
-- NULL in cases of origination with an entity
from_entity_id      INT NULL REFERENCES entity (id), 
to_entity_id        INT NOT NULL REFERENCES entity (id),
-- amount can be 0 in cases of gifts
amount              DECIMAL(9,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

A "gift" transaction would have an amount of 0 (or NULL, if you wanted to make it nullable).

An "origin" transaction (e.g. something was made, or found) would have no transaction_type, and 0 amount.

To know who the current owner of an item is, use a view that retrieves the last "to_entity_id" for that item in the transaction table, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    e.name
FROM entity AS e
INNER JOIN `transaction` AS t ON e.id = t.to_entity_id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
    FROM `transaction`
    WHERE item_id = 5) AS tx ON tx.id = t.id
```

Alternatively, you could also store the owner_id in the item table (see note above in the schema).  This would be a little redundant, and would require updating that table on each transaction, but would save a lot of expensive queries to know who owns what.